# Subversion keyword values are not seen in VisualSVN web

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

We have SVN setup on the Windows server using VisualSVN Server and on the client end we are using TortoiseSVN.

The keyword substitution works when we commit using TortosieSVN , but when I see the same file in VisualSVN web, the $Revision & $Date is not shown in files.

Is there any setup that should be done on the VisualSVN Server?

Any help here would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any setup that should be done on the VisualSVN?

No. As [Ben Reser wrote three years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19898840/960558), keywords "as-is" in web-interface is correct and good behavior

> When committing a file containing a keyword the client reduces the keyword down to be an empty copy of the keyword string and sends that to the server. The reason Subversion does not enable keywords unless the svn:keywords property is set is Subversion will never change your file content unless you tell us to do so, which the property does

But starting from SVN 1.8.0 (server-side) you can add parameter `?kw=1` to any (file) URL and get on web-access keywords expanded as it happened in Working Copy (at cat|export etc...)

VisualSVN Server (it is correct name for bundle, because just [VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) is "Subversion integration plug-in for Visual Studio") still doesn't have settings in interface to switch between old and fancy URL, but nobody prohibit you do it by hand

"INSTALLING SUBVERSION A Quick Guide" in ASF-repo: [default](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/INSTALL) and [expanded](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/INSTALL?kw=1) version of http-view for text-file with keyword in it

Comment: Thanks @Lazy Badget , I tried to expand the values using the `?kw=1 ` but that doesn't show up on the http-view. I currently have 3.5.3 version of VisualSVN server.

Comment: Ahem. You could switch to the default web interface just by unchecking **Enable automatic redirection from the legacy web interface** via VisualSVN Server Manager on Web Interface tab. You could use `?kw=1` in such case.

Answer (score 1):

VisualSVN Server's web interface does not (yet) support expanding `svn:keywords`. Drop an email to support@visualsvn.com with a summary on how you use or plan using the keyword substitution feature and we will add them as a vote up to this feature request.

Comment: @LazyBadger If everything could be as easy as adding a checkbox ;)

Comment: Well, "checkbox and a piece of business-logic to handle" if we'll continue it on a serious wave and from the developer's pure POV. But *I* know and remember about other POVs also, so do not worry about  explaining me the peculiar properties of business processes in SMB bigger than garage-team